# traefik https only works with redirect

Tags: docker-compose, traefik

I'm using traefik and its toml looks like:

```
logLevel = "DEBUG"
defaultEntryPoints = ["http","https"]

[api]
address = ":8080"

[docker]
domain = "traefik"
swarmmode = true
watch = true

[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":80"
  [entryPoints.https]
  address = ":443"
    [entryPoints.https.tls]
```

I'm using docker swarm and deploying stack(compose) file with the following labels:

```
       "traefik.backend.loadbalancer.sticky": "False",
        "traefik.docker.network": "traefik_network",
        "traefik.enable": "true",
        "traefik.frontend.rule": "PathPrefixStrip:/",
        "traefik.port": "8443",
        "traefik.protocol": "https"
```

when I curl the endpoint `curl -ik https://traefik/index` it shows in traefik access.logs that its redirecting my call correctly but I keep getting 500 internal server error. if i set https redirect under http and remove the tls line from the toml my requests works fine when I `curl -ik http://traefik/index`

Comment: Is the service you re trying to use, expose secure port and provide certificates, or is traefik handling SSL termination?
if it s the case you probably should configure youre service with http protocol and the associated port

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to this question, adding `insecureSkipVerify=true` solved my https requests issue:

```
logLevel = "DEBUG"
defaultEntryPoints = ["http","https"]
insecureSkipVerify=true

[api]
address = ":8080"

[docker]
domain = "traefik"
swarmmode = true
watch = true

[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":80"
  [entryPoints.https]
  address = ":443"
    [entryPoints.https.tls]
```